# Broken paging on suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

Right now, there are 34 suggested edits on SO. Since the default page size seems to be 30, there is a link to the second page at the bottom of the first one. Clicking there takes me to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?page=2&pagesize=30&filter=day, which contains exactly the same posts as the first page. The only difference is that the link to page 1 is now active.

Counting the entries, and trying to change the `pagesize` parameter in the URL, it seems that *all* 34 suggested edits are always shown, regardless of the parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed next deploy; thanks for noticing ;p