# When logged out, on Questions tab, after changing page size to 30 or 50 and clicking on a page number, page size resets to default 15

Tags: bug, design, pagination

The URL seems to only include either the page size or the page number, but never both. This is true for both logged in and logged out states.

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&pagesize=50
```

While logged in, the desired page size is saved and reapplied correctly, but logged out it's not.

This appears to be happening on every site with the new design.

Comment: Similar / related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338843/282094 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100570/282094

Comment: I'd like to point out that even though the underlying reason may be the same, it might actually be a different thing to fix in code, and fixing one might not resolve the problem with the other, as the pages (Questions and HNQ) are not the same. I cannot call these "exact duplicates".

Comment: Pagination is a good tag to add, but I don't want to bump. Using it finds these similar problems with the pagesize attribute in the URL: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261314/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21627/282094 (the second also status-completed, with a comment complaining that it's not).

Comment: don't worry about bumps, we're after quality here, besides it's not that far down from the top yet